# Optimisation of class / instance delegation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

How can I make this more concise?

I get a lot of instances where I need to extract an instance method and make it available as a class method.

```
class Foo
  def self.basename(bar, bar: true)
    # do stuff
  end

  def basename(*args, **kwargs) # <- make this simpler
    self.class.basename(*args, **kwargs)
  end
end
```

The goal is to be able to use:

```
Foo.basename(1, bar: false)
Foo.new.basename(1, bar: false)
```

Comment: Can you provide a much clearer example? Here you are making a class method an instance method instead which is contradicting your original question

Comment: Hi @theterminalguy thanks for your answer. I edited my post to make it clearer. Is it any better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Forwardable`, for example

```rb
class Foo
  extend Forwardable

  def self.basename(foo, bar: true)
    # do stuff
  end

  def_delegator "self.class", :basename
end
```

> I get a lot of instances

And with `def_delegators`, you can delegate many methods at once.

Comment: Don't forget to also require 'forwardable'